# How can I display the data from the json in a graph on my webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is my schema for the data, As you can see I pretty much done everything on this single file as I'm just testing it.

```
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server is up and running'));

// middleware for static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(path.resolve(__dirname), "/static")));


// form submission middleware code
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile('/pages/test.html', {root:path.resolve(__dirname)});
});



const ElectricSchema = new Schema(
    {
        voltage: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        current: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
        temperature: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
        },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
);

const Entry = mongoose.model('Entry', ElectricSchema);

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/User', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

app.get('/getdb',(req,res)=>{
    Entry.find((err,result)=>{
        if(!err){
            res.json(result);
        }
    })
})

setInterval(()=>{
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/User', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
},10000);
let randVoltage, randCurrent, randTemp;
setInterval(() => {
    randVoltage = parseInt(Math.random()*20);
    randCurrent = parseInt(Math.random()*100);
    randTemp = parseInt(Math.random()*30);
    const entry = new Entry({
        voltage:randVoltage,
        current:randCurrent,
        temperature:randTemp
    })
    entry.save().then((err,result)=>{
        if (!err) console.log(result);
    })
}, 1000);
```

And this is the html page to display my data, But i can't display it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
  <script>
    const xdata = document.getElementById('voltage');
    const xlabels = document.getElementById('createdAt');
    chartIt();
    const refreshUI = async() => {
      fetch('/getdb').then(res => res.json()).then(json => console.log(json)).catch(err => console.error(err));
      xlabel.push('current');
    }
    setInterval(refreshUI, 10000)

    function chartIt() {
      var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
      var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
          labels: xlabels,
          datasets: [{
            label: 'Voltage vs time',
            data: xdata,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
          }]
        },

      });
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Assuming `document.getElementById('voltage')` is some kind of input field you need `const xdata = document.getElementById('voltage').value;` but it is not clear what that element is. Same with the labels

Comment: Also you `push` to xLabel but have something called `xLabels` is that something in the canvas? If so, you are not showing it